# Azure SQL Server VM unable to apply service packs?

Tags: sql-server, azure, servicepacks

I have been trying to apply SQL Server 2012 SP2 to a VM instance of SQL Server 2012 SP1 without much luck. SP2 always indicates that there is no instance to upgrade. Is this a restriction of the VM to prevent these kinds of updates? Do I need to spin up another VM and migrate over to the newer version?

Comment: User permissions problem?

Comment: I am using the admin/login account used to set up the VM. If its a permissions problem its a problem for everyone as I haven't changed any kind of permission from what MS gave.